# Como verificar se foi um INSERT ou UPDATE no método save do CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Olá, tenho um script que recebo um ID por uma notificação POST junto com outros dados. Acontece que o ID é de uma transação criada em um outro sistema (os IDs não são gerados por auto_increment).

Um exemplo de dados que recebo seria:

```
{'id' : 1234, 'data' : '2014-06-02', 'etc' : 'teste'}
```

Crio o array baseado nesse json que recebo por POST.

```
$dados['Model'] = array(
   'id' => $json->id, 
   'data' => $json->data, 
   'etc' => $json->etc
);
$this->Model->save($dados);
```

Como saber se o método save() no controller fez um update ou um insert já que o id é minha primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Como eu precisava no controller acabei pondo no model o callback afterSave() da seguinte maneira.

```
class Model extends AppModel {

    public $sqlType = false;

    public function afterSave($created){
        if ($created){
            $this->sqlType = 'INSERT';
        } else {
            $this->sqlType = 'UPDATE';
        }
    }
}
```

e no controller

```
$this->Model->save($dados);
if ($this->Model->sqlType == 'INSERT'){

}
```